# VBA needed for checking a specific check box based on text box result

Tags: checkbox, ms-word, textfield, activexobject

Working in Word 2010, I need VBA code for a form that will check one of two ActiveX check boxes based on text set to populate into an ActiveX text field. (Male or Female) I'm a novice and have tried various variations of the code below:

```
Sub copyMaleFemale()
Dim ff As String
ff = CurrentFormField.Result

If ff = ("Male") Then 
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check1").Result = Checked 
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check2").Result = Unchecked

ElseIf ff = ("Female") Then
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check1").Result = Checked
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check2").Result = Unchecked

End If

End Sub
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You say ActiveX in the problem description, but the code is for form fields. What are you actually using? When you say "form" do you mean a UserForm (dialog box) or that the document is a form? Are you using any kind of forms protection? In what way is the code "not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. No brackets needed around the variable values. Something to keep in mind is that the match has to be exact, so I added a section to set both checkboxes to false if the text field is anything slightly different.

Using With/End With is always a good way to eliminate extra code and make your macro run just a little faster:

```
Sub copyMaleFemale()
    Dim ff As String
    ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").result

    If ff = "male" Then
        With ActiveDocument
            .FormFields("Check1").CheckBox.value = True
            .FormFields("Check2").CheckBox.value = False
        End With
    ElseIf ff = "female" Then
        With ActiveDocument
            .FormFields("Check1").CheckBox.value = True
            .FormFields("Check2").CheckBox.value = False
        End With
    Else
        With ActiveDocument
            .FormFields("Check1").CheckBox.value = False
            .FormFields("Check2").CheckBox.value = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I reversed True/False in the ElseIf statement (which was incorrect in my original message).  Runs perfectly..